# Google Colab don't response on pressing enter on Android and pc

Tags: google-chrome, google-colaboratory

can someone help me i used google colab before too but this time i want to enter y key and press enter. I used my laptop my android phone but still enter is not working is there any way to press enter.
This also happen sometimes while giving permission of google drive.
Entering code and then press enter button on laptop or using mobile doesn't work anyon have any solution please let me know
Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the same problem on Android. I must click on the return button to confirm a warning. But when i pressed it, it goes to the next text input and do not validate anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
!pip install colab-xterm
%load_ext colabxterm
%xterm
```